# Vectors and orthonormal matrix

Tags: vector-spaces, self-learning, orthonormal

[image]

For 2(a)(i), are the length of a =Sqrt(14) and b = sqrt(38)?

For (ii), is the angle = 4.31?

For (iii), is the answer 3.73?

For (iv), is the answer -i+j+k?

For (b) to (e), I have no idea what I should do. Would anyone mind advising me?

Comment: (i) Yes and yes, (ii) Yes (but they ask you the *cosine* of the angle, not the angle), (iii) yes and (iv) yes...Kudos!

Comment: BTW, what's your definition of *orthonormal matrix* ??

Comment: A matrix with orthonormal columns.(i.e. orthonormal set, a set of orthogonal vectors with the additional property that each vector is of unit norm.)

Comment: Well, but then an orthonormal matrix is, in particular, an orthogonal one, and thus in question (d) we have that $\;Q^tQ=I\;$ and the question is a trivial one...

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

$$||u||=||v||\implies (u+v)\cdot(u-v)=||u||^2-u\cdot v+u\cdot v= -||v||^2=\;\ldots$$

$$P^t=P^*=P^{-1}\implies ||Pu||^2=Pu\cdot Pu=u\cdot P^*Pu=u\cdot Iu=u\cdot u=||u||^2\;,\;\;etc.$$